# Help understanding beginning of Metamath proof of Cantor's Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the Metamath proof "canth" (http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/canth.html) of Cantor's Theorem, I am not able to follow it in certain cases.  Let A in step 1 be the naturals and consider a countable model.  The set on the left hand side of the subset symbol can take on the value of any subset of A (whether in the model or not) as the value of F changes.  F should be arbitrary so that the proof eliminates all of the functions which might map A onto its power set.  In this case most of the "subsets of A" do not exist in the model, or in A's power set as a result. For some values of F then, the set of x such that x is not an element of F(x), instead of being an element of A's power set as the proof requires, is a set that does not exist.  As a result it can not be a subset of anything, making the statement of step 1 false for some values of F, which ones depending on what sets are in the model.  I must be making a mistake somewhere; can anyone help me understand this better?  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it just empty, i.e. a subset of every set?

Comment: I think for some F it's empty (those in which every element of A maps to a set in P(A) containing it).  There "are" (by assumption of an arbitrary F) more than one F like that.  But if we imagine {x|x is prime} is not in the model, then those F for which {x|x is not an element of F(x)} happens to equal {x|x is prime} are the kind of cases I would like to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're proving this within a particular model of set theory, you need only consider the functions that are *in the model*, because you're not trying to show anything about the "real" power set of $A$; you're only showing something about the power set of $A$ *in that model*. Likewise, the theorem is *not* "really" true of this smaller power set - it's only going to be true *within* the model.

So $F$ must be an actual member of the model. Since the model satisfies $ZFC$ and therefore satisfies the Axiom of Separation, and since the model includes $A$ itself, $\{x \in A \mid x \notin F(x)\}$ is a set that is actually in the model.